How do I use wx.NewIdRef() correctly?
I'm on wxPython version 4.0.7.post2, and Python version 3.8.2. I've enabled warnings to catch the things I need to change in preparation for upgrading both Python and wxPython. One of the warnings I get is that wx.NewId() is deprecated. According to documentation, I should be using wx.NewIdRef(), which is supposed to be a drop-in replacement. Indeed, replacing all instances of wx.NewId() with wx.NewIdRef() works, but all the functions that take the id as a parameter trigger a new warning:

DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type WindowIDRef).
Implicit conversion to integers using int is deprecated, and may
be removed in a future version of Python.

Fine I say, let us use wx.NewIdRef().GetId() instead. i.e.:
my_id = wx.NewIdRef().GetId()
target.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.foo, id=my_id)

This gives me the following error:

wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "gs_autoIdsRefCount[winid] !=
ID_FREE" failed at ....\src\common\windowid.cpp(110) in
`anonymous-namespace'::IncIdRefCount(): id should first be reserved

OK then, since it looks like passing wx.NewIdRef triggers an implicit __int__() conversion, what if I do this: my_id = wx.NewIdRef().__int__()?
Same error. Does wx.NewIdRef have a function to manually reserve it? Nope.
So what's the deal? How am I supposed to use wx.NewIdRef() correctly? And can I use wx.Window.NewControlId() instead?

It's a while now since I did the conversions to my wxPython projects but as I recall, most of the time, slotting in NewIdRef() worked.
I ended up on the menus with this arrangement:
        e1 = wx.MenuItem(self.filem, wx.NewIdRef(), "&Encrypt/Decrypt")
        e1.SetBitmap(fs_images.getencryptBitmap())
        self.filem.Append(e1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnEncrypt, id=e1.GetId())

Which has worked faultlessly.
For areas where I need multiple Id's I've assigned them into a list and then taken them from that list i.e.
self.recent_ids = [wx.NewIdRef() for i in range(self.MaxRecent+2)]

Or, if I needed a fixed id:
TIMESTAMPOFF = wx.NewIdRef()
then:
self.autom.AppendRadioItem(TIMESTAMP_OFF, 'Turn Off Automatic Timestamps')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAutoTimeStamp, id=TIMESTAMP_OFF)

Hope it helps.

I am using now wx.Window.NewControlId() in places where a constant ID  for identifying controls would be required during lifetime of the app.
I had previously used wx.NewId() and on wxPython update had to get rid of those due to the deprecation errors (as you experienced, too).
